# Close icon doesn't work on Bootstrap Modal using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using Twitter-Bootstrap Modal. I set a close icon on Modal header. I need to active this icon to close the Modal.

```
<div class="modal-content json-modal-body" id="full-width" ng-controller="projectdetailsController" close="CloseModal()"> 
  <div class="modal-header modal-header-confirm"> 
    <h4 class="modal-title ng-binding"> 
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left"></span>{{modalOptions.headerText}} 
      <a type="button" title="Close" data-dismiss="modal"><i ng-click="CloseModal()"    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon-arrow-right pull-right"></i></a> 
    </h4> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"> 
    <pre class="Modal-pre" ng-bind-html="modalOptions.bodyText"></pre> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var modalInstance=$scope.showJSON = function(){
  var modalOptions = {
    headerText: ' JSON Schema View',
    bodyText: 'jsonSchema'
  };
  var modalDefaults = {
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/jsonModal.html'
  };        
  modalService.showModal(modalDefaults, modalOptions).then(function (result) {

  });
}
$scope.CloseModal = function () {
  $modalInstance.close(); 
}
```

I am using `ng-click="CloseModal()"` to close the modal. I also declared `close="CloseModal()"` on the parent div. How can I solve this?

I have an AngularJs controller for this modal. Can I use the controller?

Comment: What r u doing? Is this your controller?

Comment: To show the Modal i use controller.. and when the close icon is clicked i want to close the Modal.

Comment: I have posted sample example. try this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the function CloseModal() in your controller

If you use [angular-ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) it should look like this:

```
 ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance){ 

...

$scope.CloseModal = function () {
   $modalInstance.close(); 
}
```

Comment: $modalInstance is not defined

Comment: Unknown provider:  $modalInstanceProvider <-  $modalInstance is showed if i add '$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance)

Comment: do you use angular-ui bootstrap

Comment: you should use angular-ui bootstrap because it's well integrated with angular

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
var app =  angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']);
```

//controller for modal

```
 app.controller('modalCtrl',['$scope','$modalInstance', function ($scope,$modalInstance) {
        'use strict';
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    };
```

Second controller:

```
app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope','$modal', function ($scope,$modal) {

   $scope.openModal= function () {

      $modal.open({
                    backdrop: true,
                    keyboard: false,
                    backdropClick: false,
                    templateUrl: "path of your modal HTML",
                    dialogClass: "modal-content",
                    controller: 'modalCtrl',
                });
    }
```

Comment: But i used one controller .. ng-controller="projectdetailsController"
and i used Twitter-Bootstrap Modal.

Comment: do your model is opening..?

Comment: Yes... And when i press 'Esc' key, it is closing .

Comment: Try this way.. I am not understanding what you are doing.So follow t if you can, There are many other example on net. Google It..

Comment: Do you have included $modalInstance in you controller as i did..?

Comment: You have used $modalInstance in one controller and $modal in another....but i have one controller. and i used $modal.